# Problem with understanding how to use this theory in a concrete example

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Im hoping this is a question that is okey to ask, without having the thread removed.

Im having trouble understanding how to use a theorem in the book we are using in the complex analysis course.

The theorem states the following:

Suppose $f$ is a function holomorphic in $D[z_0,R]$. Then f can be represented as a power series at $z_0$, with radius of convergence $\geq R$:

$f(z) = \sum_{k\geq0}c_k(z-z_0)^k$ with $c_k=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{f(w)}{(w-w_0)^{k+1}}$

I understand that it can be represented as a power series, but the thing I don't understand is how and where I'm supposed to use the second statement, with $c_k$. I don't find any concrete examples in my book, and therefore I would like to ask if anyone can give me simple explanation of its usage, and when its good to use.

Thanks!

Comment: One of the interests is that by Taylor expansion gives: $c_k=k! f^{(k)}(x_0)$, the $k$-th derivative in $x_0$ without needing to compute a general expression for this derivative.

Comment: You've surely got a typo here? The $w_0$ should  be $z_0$. You also have to specify the contour $\gamma$ (I can guess but that's not good enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of trying to prove the following statement:

- A priori: The function $f$ is complex-differentiable in the region
- Then we can show: The function $f$ is infinitely differentiable and has a power series.

This is a very strong theorem: In real analysis, there are a lot of functions that are one-time differentiable but not infinitely many times; Also in real analysis there are infinitely-differentiable functions that are not represented by a power series. Complex holomorphic functions are much better behaved.

So suppose $f$ is a function that is holomorphic (i.e. complex-differentiable) on $D[z_0,R]$. Then by [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) it is infinitely differentiable, and we have $f^{(n)}(w_0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma\frac{f(w)}{(w-w_0)^{n+1}}\mathrm{d}w$.

The point here is that we are *integrating*: The integrant is clearly integrable on the contour, which means that we can find the derivative without actually taking derivatives!

Now using the taylor expansion formula $f(w) = \sum_{k\geq0}\frac{f^{(n)}(w_0)}{n!}(w-w_0)^k$ we obtain your result.

If you want to find the coefficients $\frac{f^{(n)}(w_0)}{n!}$ concretely for a specific function, the integral formula is usually not very practical. Instead, more common methods of finding derivatives are preferred.